# What is a staging table and how do you protect data loss when transferring the data?

Tags: oracle-12c, c#, rdbms, bulk-insert

What is a staging table? What is it used for? Are there best practices that should be applied? I'm working in Oracle right now. Are staging tables platform dependent? I'm performing a bulk copy with Devart's OracleLoader C# class. To my knowledge you can't perform this type of operation on a table with enabled triggers(used to add a sequenced primary key).

Another question related to staging tables. How do you protect data loss when transferring data from a staging table to it's permanent home(permanent table?)

I believe I have a basic understanding of what a staging table is. From my understanding it is just a location to temporarily store data before moving that data to its permanent home.

Answer (score 1):

> I believe I have a basic understanding of what a staging table is.
>   From my understanding it is just a location to temporarily store data
>   before moving that data to its permanent home.

Yes, it is.

> To my knowledge you can't perform this type of operation on a table
>   with enabled triggers(used to add a sequenced primary key).

This is a restriction of direct path load, not staging tables.

[Direct Path Loads, Integrity Constraints, and Triggers](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-sql-loader-conventional-and-direct-loads.html#GUID-973925DA-8F86-49C1-A707-4564DC3B57AE)

Triggers fire during conventional path loads.

> How do you protect data loss when transferring data from a staging
>   table to it's permanent home(permanent table?)

You don't. Direct path loads do not generate the redo that would make possible recovering the data affected by it in case of a recovery situation (this is to improve performance). Since it is just a temporary location, if it is damaged or lost, you can just start over and repeat the loading process.

If you want it to be protected, then use conventional path load.